# PHP Execution stops in between

Tags: php, safari

I have no idea why this happens, and it seems to happen on safari not on chrome.

I am running a simple facebook connect operation. The pages gets redirected to facebook and facebook returns the control back to my page.

When to control comes back to my website. The does not complete the execution. It just halts. I put it some debugging "echos" in there. This is what it is.

```
<?php $a = array("me" => "you"); ?>
<?=var_dump($a)?>
<?=var_dump($_POST)?>


//OUTPUT
array(1) { ["me"]=> string(3) "you" } array(0) {
```

Comment: view the source of the page.. I doubt that's the full output.

Comment: Did you check your server logs for errors? If the PHP output just ends right this there is most like a segmentation fault.